Matrix multiplication code runs without error but gives no output
This code for matrix multiplication asks the user for input and everything but doesn't give any output. Can anyone please help?
#include <stdio.h>

int i, j, k, l = 0;
int r1, r2, c1, c2;

void matMul(int m1[r1][c1], int m2[r2][c2], int res[r1][c2]){
    for (int a = 0; a < r1; a++){
        for (int  b = 0; b < c2; b++){
            res[a][b] = 0;
        }
    }

    while (i < r1) { 
        if (j == c1) {
            j,k = 0;
            l++;
        }
        else if (l == c2) {
            l = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else if (i>r1){
            break;
        }
        res[i][l] += m1[i][j]*m2[k][l];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    printf("Resultant Matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < c2; j++){
            printf("%d\t", res[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main(){
    printf("Enter the number of rows for first matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &r1);
    printf("Enter the number of columns for first matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &c1);
    printf("Enter the elements of first matrix:\n");
    int m1[r1][c1];
    for (int a = 0; a < r1; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < c1; b++){
            scanf("%d", &m1[a][b]);
        }
    }

    printf("Enter the number of rows for second matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &r2);
    printf("Enter the number of columns for second matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &c2);
    if (c1!=r2) {
        printf("Matrices can't be multiplied with each other.\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Enter the elements of second matrix:\n");
    int m2[r2][c2];
    for (int a = 0; a < r2; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < c2; b++){
            scanf("%d", &m2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int res[r1][c2];
    matMul(m1, m2, res);
}


scanf("%d", &m2[i][j]); should be scanf("%d", &m2[a][b]);  You used the wrong variables for the indices.  Typo.

This doesn't do what you think it does: j,k = 0;

Matrix multiplication code runs without error but gives no output -- If this is the case, the program is not running without error.  That's like saying "I can drive my car, but the brakes do not work".  From the title, persons would be looking for a program that would have produced valid output, but for some reason, the printf() (or whatever output function) was not producing the output.

Thanks, @TomKarzes, The code works flawlessly now.

Thanks, @dbush, The code works flawlessly now.
